# PHP beginner palindrome script

Tags: php, algorithm, palindrome

I was working on (for fun) writing a script that would recognize palindromes. So far, I'm successful with "Kayak", "Racecar", "Anna", "A man a plan a canal Panama": yet variations on the latter phrase such as "amanaplana canalpan ama" gives me problems.

*As a side note:* I do understand that using PCRE would make things a lot easier for me, but I'm not fluent in it and one of my major aims was to understand the algorithm behind checking for palindromes.

```
 <?php
$word = "amanaplana canalpan ama";

$space = " ";
$word_smallcase = strtolower($word);        

$word_array = str_split($word_smallcase);   

if(in_array($space, $word_array)){      

    for($m = 0; $m<count($word_array); $m = $m + 1){
        if($word_array[$m] == $space)
            unset($word_array[$m]);
    }
}
$count = 0;
$scan_count = -1;
for($i = 0; $i < (count($word_array)/2); $i = $i + 1){

    for($j = count($word_array); $j > (count($word_array)/2); $j = $j - 1){

        if($word_array[$i]==$word_array[$j]){
            $count = $count + 1;
            break;
            }
        }
    $scan_count = $scan_count + 1;

        }
if ($count == $scan_count){
    echo $word." is a palindrome";
}
else{

    echo $word ." is NOT a palindrome";
}


?>
```

I'd appreciate a response regarding:

- The identification of the bug I'm having.
- Recommendations as to
  how I could possibly improve the code (I'd be happy if I could make
  things work without resorting to $count or $scan_count which seem, to
  my eye, relatively amateurish).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things going on here...

First, I'm not sure if you're aware that `unset`'ing the array doesn't actually remove the indices:

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
unset($array[2]);
var_dump($array);
/* array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
} */
```

So you're going to have some undefined offsets when you iterate over the elements in the array. To go one by one, you should use the `foreach` loop control.

Another issue lies in the nested for loop here:

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($word_array)/2); $i = $i + 1){

    for($j = count($word_array); $j > (count($word_array)/2); $j = $j - 1){
```

Given "amanaplanacanalpanama", look at what you're doing:

comparing, step by step (btw, you're off by 1 on the initializer for $j... `$word_array[count($word_array)]` is pointing at the 'm' in panama, not the 'a'.):

```
a eq to a?              j is 22          i is 0
                scan_count: -1   count: 1
m eq to a?              j is 22          i is 1
m eq to m?              j is 21          i is 1
                scan_count: 0    count: 2
a eq to a?              j is 22          i is 2
                scan_count: 1    count: 3
```

`a eq to a` is fine, and matches... m is found on the next iteration, but when you get to the next 'a', you're finding the original 'a' at the end of panama...

As a side note, since you are starting over from the very end every time, it would be horribly inefficient `O(n^2)` given a sufficiently large string...

Obligatory solution:

```
$word = "amanaplana canalpan ama";

$j = strlen ($word)-1;
$pal = true;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word)/2; ++$i, --$j) {

    // skip spaces
    while ($word[$i] === " ") {$i++;}
    while ($word[$j] === " ") {$j--;}

    echo "$word[$i] eq $word[$j]?\n";
    if ($word[$i] !== $word[$j])    {
        $pal = false;
        break;
        }
}

if ($pal) print "yes"; else print "no";
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you're testing on a word-for-word basis, and that will definitely cause bugs in cases where words are uneven across the palindrome.

The easy way to see if a string is palandromic in PHP:

```
$test = str_replace( array(',', '.', ' '
                     //, and any other punctuation you aren't using
                     ), '', $input );

$test = strtolower( $test );
echo $input . ' is ' . 
             ( ( strrev( $test ) == $test )? "": "not " )
             ' palandromic.';
```

As to your code: iterating through an array and removing things at the same time is an invitation to trouble. You're better just using str_replace. If that isn't an option, I would use:

```
// this takes more space, but it is easier to understand.
$tmp = array();
for($m = 0; $m<count($word_array); $m++){ // ++ is the same as $m = $m + 1
    if($word_array[$m] != $space)
        $tmp[] = $word_array[$m];
}
$word_array = $tmp;
```

If strrev (reverses a string) is not available:

```
$l = count( $word_array ) / 2; // cache this, no sense in recounting
$is_palindromic = TRUE;
for( $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++ )
{
    if( $word_array[ $i ] != $word_array[ ( -1 - $i ) ] )
    {
        $is_palindromic = FALSE;
        break;
    }
}

echo $input . ' is ' . 
         ( $is_palindromic )? "": "not " )
         ' palandromic.';
```

Comment: The var name "word_array" is misleading... str_split is actually returning an array of letters.

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
string phrase = "my phrase here"

int i = 0
int j = phrase.length - 1

while i < j:
  if phrase[i] is not alphanumeric:
    i++;
    continue;
  if phrase[j] is not alphanumeric:
    j--;
    continue;
  if phrase[i] != phrase[j]
    return false;
  i++;
  j--;

return true
```

Answer (score 0):

I **think** it is possible to just remove all the spaces and ignore *words* completely. Just split into two (or thereabouts if string length is an odd number), reverse any half and then see if they match.

```
$word = "amanaplana canalpan ama";

$sanitizedWord = preg_replace("'\s+'", '', strtolower($word));
$halfway = strlen($sanitizedWord)/2;
$roundedDownMidPoint = floor($halfway);

$firstHalf = substr($sanitizedWord, 0, $roundedDownMidPoint);
$secondHalf = substr($sanitizedWord, is_float($halfway) ? $roundedDownMidPoint+1 : $halfway);

if ($firstHalf === strrev($secondHalf)) {
    echo $sanitizedWord." is a palindrome";
}
```

Tested with "Kayak", "Racecar", "Anna", "A man a plan a canal Panama" and "amanaplana canalpan ama" which are all identified correctly as palindromes.

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I was looking for a way to implement it without resorting to such libraries built into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a="amanaplana canalpan ama";
echo "String entered: " . $a;
$b= preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $a);
$org= strtolower($b);
$chk= strrev($org);
echo "<br/>";
if ($org==$chk)
{ echo "Palindrome"; }
else
{ echo "Not Palindrome"; }
?>
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've wanted the answer, but thanks :)